# How do define a monad transformer that is the composition of two arbitrary monad transformers?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I want to write something similar to the following:

```
newtype FooT c d m a = FooT { unFooT :: (c (d m)) a }

instance (MonadTrans c, MonadTrans d) => MonadTrans (FooT c d) where
  lift = FooT . lift . lift
```

However, this snippet will not compile:

```
Could not deduce (Monad (d m)) arising from a use of ‘lift’
```

I understand why this won't compile; we don't know that the application of an arbitrary transformer `d m` is itself a monad. However, I'm not sure of the best way to proceed.
Is there a clean way to make something like this work? Presumably it would go through if I could add a constraint along the lines of `Monad (d m)` to the left-hand-side of the instance declaration, but I don't know how to do so since `m` is not bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `QuantifiedConstraints` GHC extension, this is

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

instance (MonadTrans c, MonadTrans d, forall m. Monad m => Monad (d m)) =>
         MonadTrans (FooT c d) where
  lift = FooT . lift . lift
```

`m` in the constraint is not the same `m` as in `lift`. The quantified constraint simply means what it says ("for any `m :: Type -> Type`, if `Monad m` require `Monad (d m)`"), and in `lift` that universal statement is being instantiated with the particular `m`  being passed as argument to `lift`. Thus `lift`'s `m` does not escape its scope.

Answer (score 2):

Since [*transformers 0.6*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/changelog) the `MonadTrans` type class has had a requirement [that it preserves `Monad`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19922).

This means the definition of [`MonadTrans`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) is:

```
type Lifting cls trans = forall m. cls m => cls (trans m)

class Lifting Monad trans => MonadTrans trans where
  lift :: Monad m => m ~> trans m
```

The composition of transformers (`ComposeT`), which you call `FooT` doesn't need to specify the lifting, so the code you supplied in your question should work for versions *0.6+*.

[`ComposeT` already exists in *deriving-trans*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-trans-0.3.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Compose.html)

```hs
newtype Ok m a = Ok (Int -> Bool -> m a)
  deriving
    ( Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Contravariant
    , Monad, MonadPlus, MonadCont, MonadIO, MonadFix,
    , MonadFail, MonadZip
    )
  via ReaderT Int (ReaderT Bool m)

  deriving MonadTrans
  via ComposeT (ReaderT Int) (ReaderT Bool)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, this is great -- figured it would exist somewhere already but couldn't find anything.